# A notation mistake in MinMaximizer?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I've been reading the game theory from [this source](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/agta/). In there clearly mentioned that:

[image: Formula]

But I think it's not true. Isn't it true to write it as follows:

$$\min_{x_2\in X_2} (x^*_1)^TAx_2 = \min_{x_2\in X_2} \max_{x_1\in X_1}(x_1)^TAx_2$$

Thanks

Comment: Note that the difference between $\displaystyle min_{x_2\in X_2} $ and $\displaystyle \min_{x_2\in X_2}$ is only a single keystroke. I edited accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry, I made mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think the second equality is true, then so is the first. This follows from the [minimax theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem). In particular, we have that

$$ \max_{x_1 \in X_1} \min_{x_2 \in X_2} \, x_1^T A x_2 = \min_{x_2 \in X_2} \max_{x_1 \in X_1} \, x_1^T A x_2, $$

as long as $X_1$ and $X_2$ are compact and convex. These are standard assumptions in game theory.

Comment: Thanks to you, the phrase I mentioned is one of the steps proving the equality, and I have problem with this definition. Why the max is out of the phrase, I think it should be inside.

Comment: Could you be more specific about where in the linked page (with various lecture notes) your question refers to?

Comment: Sure, in lecture 4,
 page 7.[http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/agta/lec4_2016.pdf]

Comment: I see. In the lecture notes, this is just a definition. You take it to be true.

Comment: Many thanks to you for your time.